# joint probability and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[image]

I came to ask this question because I couldn't understand an answer in [What are the differences between "Marginal Probability Distribution" and "Conditional Probability Distribution"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485156/what-are-the-differences-between-marginal-probability-distribution-and-condit/485172?newreg=2802479b86534f31b6af62e359d72f48)

In the answer, the chart above is shown, and the difference between marginal probability distribution and conditional probability distribution is explained.

While I understood the difference of the two, I suddenly got a bit confused about the calculation of conditional probabilities.

The answer in that post contained this:
[image]

If **P**(**X** = x<sub>1</sub>) = 0.6, I would expect **P**(**Y** = y<sub>1</sub>) = 0.617.

And if joint probabilities is simply the product of two probabilities,
**P**(**X** = x<sub>1</sub>, **Y** = y<sub>1</sub>) = **P**(**X** = x<sub>1</sub>)**P**(**Y** = y<sub>1</sub>),
then doesn't that mean

**P**(**Y** = y<sub>1</sub>|**X** = x<sub>1</sub>) = 0.617, considering the **P**(**X** = x<sub>1</sub>)s will cancel out?

Sorry if this seems like a lazy question. I will definitely try to find out what's happening before an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of your mistake is in the sentence: "And if joint probabilities is simply the product of two probabilities" - This is only true for independent variables. This is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I am still a bit confused about how to calculate P(X|Y). If x and y are dependent variables, it would mean P(X|Y) = P(X,Y)/P(Y) = P(X|Y)(P(Y)/P(Y). Does this mean I would be able to solve this question only when P(X,Y) is a given..? (obviously this is something I should look up...)

Comment: Nevermind I think I understood what it means. It seems like if you had more context in a given question, you can calculate P(X|Y) on other basis given from the question.