# Is the intercept fit differently for each regressor in Multiple Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, intercept

is the intercept B0 in y = B0 + B1X1 + ....  fit differently for every feature x1.

Is it different for every feature coefficient or the same for all feature coefficients and why so?

Comment: Because B0 is not multiplied by X1, it is always B0.

Comment: How is B0 multiplied by X1? It is added to B1 times X1 as the formula clearly indicates.

Answer (score 3):

**NO**, there is only one intercept in the model, with only one value. It is not clear from where your misconception comes, but from the algebra
$$ y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} +\dotso +\epsilon_i $$
which is the multiple linear regression model, the constant term (intercept) $\beta_0$ has only one index $_0$, is only one symbol, and can only represent one number.

The different predictor variables $x$ have indices $_{i1}, _{i2}, \dotsc$ the last number $1,2,\dotsc$ indicating *which* predictor variable it is. This number does not occur with the intercept, so there is no connection.

@user20637 says in a comment *The intercept will (often) change if a predictor is removed or added. This may be the source of the OPs misconception*.  If so, the following post will help you: [Why is the intercept in multiple regression changing when including/excluding regressors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429526/why-is-the-intercept-in-multiple-regression-changing-when-including-excluding-re/429608#429608)

Comment: The intercept will (often) change if a predictor is removed or added. This may be the source of the OPs misconception.

Comment: Can not edit since it only involves one word, but it should be "have" and not "has" in the first sentence of the last paragraph. +1 though.