# Interpreting when a regression coefficient is significant

Tags: regression, self-study, inference, interpretation, categorical-encoding

Consider the following regression model:

$y_i=\beta_1+\beta_2x_{i,2}+\beta_3x_{i,3}+\beta_4x_{i,2}x_{i,3}+\epsilon_i,$

where $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2).$ Here, $x_2$ is binary variable

$$X_2 =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if method 1} \\
1, & \text{if method 2}
\end{cases}$$

and $x_3$ is continuous variable.

If I find $\beta_2$ is significant what does it mean? Does it mean $X_2$ variable is significant? what does it mean by $X_2$ variable is significant? is it there is evidence of association between $Y$ and $X_2$? How is to know whether there is evidence of difference between two methods?

Also, what is the interpretation when I find $\beta_4$ significant?

Comment: Are you asking 'what does significance' mean - for which there are many questions asked before that answer this - or maybe something else? It is not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: Is your question about the interpretation of the intercept? Like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308556/) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429526/)

Answer (score 11):

*Without* an interaction (product) term X2X3, the p-value for β2 provides a test of the null hypothesis that the adjusted mean difference between the two groups (controlling for X3) is zero in the population. In other words, a small p-value would indicate that the groups differ in their (adjusted) means (method 2 - method 1), controlling for X3 (this is equivalent to an analysis of covariance).

*With* the interaction (product) term X2X3 included, the interpretation is different. In that case, β2 gives the mean difference (method 2 - method 1) when X3 = 0 (which may or may not be meaningful, depending on whether X3 has a meaningful zero point; centering X3 prior to the analysis could help with the interpretation if raw X3 does not have a meaningful zero point). As a consequence, the p-value for β2 *with* interaction term provides a test of whether the groups differ in their means at the point X3 = 0.

See Chapters 8 and 9 in:

Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G. & Aiken, L. S. (2003). *Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences*. Mahwah, NJ: Erlbaum.

Answer (score 5):

First of all “significance” means very little and is entirely arbitrary.  So interpret regression coefficients whether or not they are “significant”.  To say that $\beta_{i} \neq 0$ is to say that $X_i$ is associated with $Y$ after accounting for the effects of the other $X$s if linearity, additivity, and possibly other model assumptions hold.  One might also say that a nonzero coefficient implies that the corresponding $X$ predicts $Y$ to some extent, and that this prediction is different from what one would get had the model not included this $X$.  Note that that language is unclear about true vs. estimated effects.  An intro to regression may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).

Comment: I suspect the question is asking how to evaluate the results when there is an interaction included.  For testing significance, that would suggest an omnibus F test; and for interpretation, it means interpreting the interaction term along with the coefficient of $X_i$ itself.

Comment: Yes, and best to interpret with double difference contrasts and a series of single differences at different levels of interacting factor.  This is general and works with nonlinear effects.